# JPA 2.0 CriteriaQuery on tables in @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, database, jpa, criteria, jpa-2.0

I have two entities in a `@ManyToMany` relationship.

```java
// Output has 4 other @ManyToOne relationships if that matters    
@Entity @Table public class Output {
    @Id public String address;
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Interval.class,
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "output_has_interval",
               joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "output_address", 
                                          referencedColumnName = "address")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "interval_start",
                                          referencedColumnName = "start"),
                              @JoinColumn(name = "interval_end", 
                                          referencedColumnName = "end")})
    Collection<Interval> intervals;

@IdClass(IntervalPK.class) // I'll omit this one.
@Entity @Table public class Interval {
    @Id public Calendar start;
    @Id public Calendar start;
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Output.class,
                mappedBy = "intervals",
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Collection<Output> outputs;
```

The join table is called `output_has_interval` between `output` and `interval`.

How do I do `CriteriaQuery` like this?

```sql
SELECT `output`.`address`
FROM   `output`, `output_has_interval`, `interval`
WHERE  `output`.`address` = `output_has_interval`.`output_address`
AND    `interval`.`start` = `output_has_interval`.`interval_start`
AND    `interval`.`end` = `output_has_interval`.`interval_end`
AND    `interval`.`start` >= '2011-04-30'
```

This works as expected if I issue it in MySQL.

(I have the corresponding static meta model classes as well, on request I'll could post them - nothing fancy tho'.)

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Output> cq = cb.createQuery(Output.class);
Root<Output> root= cq.from(Output.class);
CollectionJoin<Output, Interval> join = root.join(Output_.intervals);
Expression<Calendar> start = join.get(Interval_.start);
Predicate pred = cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(start, /* calendar for '2011-04-30' */);
cq.where(pred);
TypedQuery<Output> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
```

However `tq.getResultList` returns every `output` row from my database. Any idea?

(On a side note: Hibernate (the provider I'm using) generates many `select` statements when I issue this query, one for every relationship `Output` has, sometimes more.)

Edit.: I wrote:

> `tq.getResultList` returns every
>   `output` row from my database

To clarify it: it returns more than just every `output` row from my database. It actually does a join using `output` and `interval` however the predicate:

```
`interval`.`start` >= '2011-04-30'
```

doesn't get satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'll managed to solve my riddle on my own.

First of all: the whole problem originated from the fact that I'm a lousy programmer. I iterated over `TypedQuery<Output>.getResultList()` and accessed every `Interval` in `Output.intervals` in a recursive manner, thus Hiberate loaded lazily the requested objects generating a handful of `select` statements.

However I had to get a hold of those `Interval` instaces somehow. The following change to my `CriteriaQuery` did the trick.

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery(); // or createQuery(Tuple.class)
Root<Output> root= cq.from(Output.class); // from clause
CollectionJoin<Output, Interval> join = root.join(Output_.intervals);
Path<String> addressPath = root.get(Output_.address); // mind these Path objects
Path<Calendar> startPath = join.get(Interval_.start); // these are the key to success!
cq.multiselect(addressPath, startPath); // select clause
Expression<Calendar> start = join.get(Interval_.start);
Predicate pred = cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(start, /* calendar for '2011-04-30' */);
cq.where(pred); // where clause
TypedQuery<Tuple> tq = em.createQuery(cq); // holds Tuples
for (Tuple tuple : tq.getResultsList()) {
    String address = tuple.get(addressPath);
    Calendar start = tuple.get(startPath);
...
```

### Edit

I've just realized that I could've used `Path<T>` objects instead `Expression<T>` objects (or vice versa) as `Path<T>` extends `Expression<T>`. Oh well...

Comment: I'm using root.join synthax, and when I check Hibernate logs, I can see the query is working, but it count me the id of my objects, instead of listing them ...

Comment: @Alex Well without seeing your code I can't tell what could be the problem.

Comment: I've made a custom class which implements Specification<Employees>. In the method *toPredicate()* of this class I build a Predicate List and I convert this array to a single Predicate to be returned like this : 
`return criteriaBuilder.and(filters.toArray(new Predicate[filters.size()]));`.
In my Predicate List I add a JOIN, to get *Employees* from a specific *Group* (it's a ManyToMany relationship). 
`filters.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join("groups").get("id"), this.groupId));`
And at this join, the query isn't called,I can only see a `select count` in hibernate logs. thx for any advice

Comment: @Alex Can you post your code to pastebin or somewhere?

Comment: Thank you very much for the interest here is the link to my custom class code : http://pastebin.com/tj7dX0DB. I simply instanciate this class in my WebService and call this JPA repository method : `Page<Employee> findAll(Specification<Employee> spec, Pageable pageable);`. Then I get a select count() query instead of getting actual elements. That's all :)

Comment: @Alex Some ideas: in your `toPredicate` method you are building the *where* expression only as far as I can see. The part that usually comes in the *select* clause is missing from here. In my example you can see that I call `CriteriaQuery.from`, which will tell the parser/builder that actually want *select * from Output* or something like that. You are not even using the `CriteriaQuery` object in your method. So I guess the mistake is when you use the result ot `toPredicate`. More importantly make your code more simple at first. Issue a basic query, without filters first. Build from there.

Comment: ok, but I'm only building a where clause because the select clause is done in my toPredicate `Root<Employee> root` argument. In fact this is working, if I remove my condition with the join <Employee, group>. What I suspect is Pageable item, making JPA tells to Hibernate to perform a count query among other queries to be sure there is results to retrieve. This count query works and return me 1 row, but the following query to select the elements is not performed, even if the count have not returned 0. This is off-topic so I'll open a subject, but thx for advices !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97431/discussion-between-alex-and-kohanyi-robert).