# JPA query with @ManyToMany relationship and no navigation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, jpql

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741096/jpa-multiple-joins), I have these (almost the same) classes:

```
public class Project {
    @ManyToMany 
    private Set<Person> resources;
    // get and set of resources
}
public class Person {
}
```

The difference is that my properties are private (using beans as entities).

The question is: how would I create a query to return all projects of a determined person (in JPQL and/or using CriteriaQuery)?

I found all these other similar questions, but none helped me, because all of them rely on the navigation from `Project` to `Person` (which doesn't exist querying from `Person`):

- [JPQL ManyToMany select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425835/jpql-manytomany-select)
- [@ManyToMany JPA 2 complex query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892305/manytomany-jpa-2-complex-query)
- [JPA 2.0 CriteriaQuery on tables in @ManyToMany relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635287/jpa-2-0-criteriaquery-on-tables-in-manytomany-relationship)

I wouldn't like to insert a property inside 'Person' just to be able to make the query, because it doesn't make sense in my model.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select project from Project project
join project.resources person
where person.id = :personId
```

I'll let you translate this to criteria if you really want it, but I don't hink using Criteria for such a basic static query offers any advantage.